# Trying to understand this gradient

Tags: calculus

I need some help to understand how a derivative was calculated since I can't see how the derivative of this function:

$$
     x = 2 \frac{\sum_{k=1}^2 w_k \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{kn}b_{kn}}{\sum_{k=1}^2 w_k \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{kn} + b_{kn}}
$$

is this one:

$$
   \frac{\partial x}{\partial b_i}= 2 \frac{(w_1^2 - w_2^2)\left[ \sum_{n=1}^N a_nb_n - a_i\sum_{n=1}^{N} (a_n + b_n) \right] + Nw_2(w_1+w_2)(1-2a_i)}{\left[ (w_1-w_2) \sum_{n=1}^N(a_n + b_n) + 2Nw_2 \right]^2}
$$

Shouldn't it be something along these lines:

$$
\frac{\partial x}{\partial b_i}= 2 \frac{\left[ \sum_{k=1}^2 w_k \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{kn} + b_{kn} \right] \left( \sum_{k=1}^2 w_k \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{kn} \right) + \left[ \sum_{k=1}^2 w_k \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{kn}b_{kn} \right] \left( N \sum_{k=1}^2 w_k \right)}{\left[ \sum_{k=1}^2 w_k \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_{kn} + b_{kn} \right]^2}
$$

What I'm missing? My guess is that they expanded some sums, but how they obtained all these additional terms?

EDIT: Corrected the formula to add a missing factor of 2.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there any relationship between $a_{kn}, b_{kn}$ and $a_n, b_n$ ?

Comment: Yes, $a_{n} = [a_{1n}, a_{2n}]$, and $b_{n} = [b_{1n}, b_{2n}]$;

Comment: Where does come the expected relation ? The denominator seems wrong since it mixes vector and scalar. Please clarify

Comment: This is meant to be the Generalized Dice Score for two classes $(k=2)$, which is used as a loss function for some models. Then, $a_n$ and $b_n$ are the true and predicted values for the element $n$. And $a_{in}$ and $b_{in}$ are the probability values for element $n$ for class $i$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\phi
&=&
1-2
\frac{w_1 \sum_n (p_n r_n) + w_2 \sum_n (1-p_n) (1-r_n)}{w_1 \sum_n (p_n+r_n)+w_2 \sum_n (1-p_n)+(1-r_n)} \\
&=&
1-2
\frac{(w_1+w_2) P - w_2 S + N w_2}
{(w_1-w_2) S + 2Nw_2}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $P=\sum_n (p_n r_n), S=\sum_n (p_n+r_n)$.

The derivative writes
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial p_n}
=
-2
\frac{[(w_1+w_2)r_n-w_2]D-(w_1-w_2)[(w_1+w_2) P - w_2 S + N w_2]}{D^2}
$$
where $D=(w_1-w_2) S + 2Nw_2$.

the numerator simplifies into
\begin{eqnarray*}
&&
(w_1^2-w_2^2)(r_n S-P)
+ 2 N w_2 (w_1+w_2)r_n
-2 Nw_2^2
- N (w_1-w_2) w_2 \\
&&(w_1^2-w_2^2)(r_n S-P)
+ 2 N w_2 (w_1+w_2)r_n
- N (w_1+w_2) w_2 \\
&&(w_1^2-w_2^2)(r_n S-P)
+ N w_2 (w_1+w_2) (2 r_n -1)
\end{eqnarray*}

The derivative writes
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial p_n}
=
-2
\frac
{(w_1^2-w_2^2)(r_n S-P)
+ N w_2 (w_1+w_2) (2 r_n -1)}
{D^2}
$$

Comment: Thanks! I never thought about replacing the summations as variables and the $p_{2n} = 1 - p_n$. A quick question, if we extend it to $n$ classes, these replacements won't apply right?

Comment: I think that the generalization is straightforward as long as you maintain the requirement that $\sum_k p_{nk} = 1, \forall n$

Comment: I see, then the derivative will be taken with respect to $p_{kn}$ instead? Thanks again for your help!